# Allow users to edit their own files and folders

Tags: filesystems, network-share, file-permissions, windows-server-2016

I'm setting up file and storage services on Windows Server 2016 wherein I wish to allow AD users to have their own folders under a common folder where they will save and modify files. However they can modify and save files under their own folder but can view only files from other user's folders.

How can I go about setting up such hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the parent folder, disable inheritance and set the users are Read/List only.

On each user folder, set all the other users (assuming in a Security Group or OU) to Read/List. Set the folder's owner to the appropriate owner user, then set Owner Permissions to R/W.

Comment: Was pretty much confused between inheritance and setting each and every folder Read/List. After some trial and error along with your answer given, I was able to achieve exactly what I needed!